# how to hide the cells of table who are having background color as a grey from ms word document using vba macros

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am having so many different types of tables in my word doc. From that grey color cells are not usable so i have to hide it( dont want to delete it). tables number of rows and columns are always not same. so i dont know how to hide the cells of table who are having background color as a grey from ms word document using vba macros????

```
Sub ClearTableBGColor()
    Dim t As Table

    For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
    If t.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Grey Then
     t.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have vertically merged cells, you can only hide _complete_ tables as you can not address each row individually. Please consider to test my first example. Also it is not possible to have all white cells visible without any grey ones visible, as word cannot hide partly rows without deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the best you'll get with tables like your screenshots show is something along the lines of what the following macro does.

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Tbl As Table, c As Long
With ActiveDocument
  For Each Tbl In .Tables
    With Tbl.Range
      For c = 1 To .Cells.Count
        With .Cells(c).Range
          If .Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdGray25 Then
            With .ParagraphFormat
              .SpaceBefore = 0
              .SpaceAfter = 0
              .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceExactly
              .LineSpacing = 0.7
            End With
            .Font.Hidden = True
          End If
        End With
      Next
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note that you cannot completely hide a row this way.

Comment: @neharaut In that case, you should mark the correct answers for tables with & without merged cells as answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

To recognize all sorts of "grey" you may compare red/green/blue parts of the background color. If they are identical, then the color is either black (all zero), white (all 255) or grey.

If grey, then you may hide the whole table by hiding its font.

First example (hiding the whole table based on first cell's background):

```
Sub ClearTableBGColor()
    Dim t As Table
    Dim SearchColor As Long
    Dim r As Byte, g As Byte, b As Byte

    For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
        SearchColor = t.Range.Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor
        If SearchColor < 0 Then SearchColor = &H1000000 + SearchColor
        r = SearchColor Mod 256             ' red part
        g = SearchColor \ 256 Mod 256       ' green part
        b = SearchColor \ (2 ^ 16) Mod 256  ' blue part
        If (r = g) And (g = b) Then         ' all parts identical?
            If r > 0 And r < 255 Then       ' neither black nor white?
                t.Range.Font.Hidden = True  ' hide table with grey background
            End If
        End If
    Next t
End Sub
```

Second example: Hiding each row idividually based on the row's first cell:

```
Sub ClearTableRowsBGColor()
    Dim t As Table
    Dim tableRow As Row
    Dim SearchColor As Long
    Dim r As Byte, g As Byte, b As Byte

    For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For Each tableRow In t.Rows
            SearchColor = tableRow.Range.Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor
            If SearchColor < 0 Then SearchColor = &H1000000 + SearchColor
            r = SearchColor Mod 256             ' red part
            g = SearchColor \ 256 Mod 256       ' green part
            b = SearchColor \ (2 ^ 16) Mod 256  ' blue part
            If (r = g) And (g = b) Then         ' all parts identical?
                If r > 0 And r < 255 Then       ' neither black nor white?
                    tableRow.Range.Font.Hidden = True  ' hide grey
                End If
            End If
        Next tableRow
    Next t
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, assuming you've used one of the standard grey shades, is to use code like:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Tbl As Table, r As Long
With ActiveDocument
  For Each Tbl In .Tables
    With Tbl
      For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
        With .Rows(r).Range
          If .Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdGray25 Then .Font.Hidden = True
        End With
      Next
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The above code assumes the shading is 25% grey. Other possibility is 50% grey, or wdGray50. Any other grey-scale shading requires more extensive code, such as Asger posted. By setting .Font.Hidden = True, you can toggle the hidden rows' visibility on/off via the ¶ button on the Ribbon's Home tab.

**Note:** The above code assumes there are no vertically merged/split cells in the tables; if there are, you'll need to provide more details about the table structures.

Comment: Hii , my table has vertically merged cells. How to code for this ?

Comment: @neharaut As I noted in my answer, you'll need to provide more details about the table structures. For example, are entire columns (or all except a header row) merged. Which columns are affected? Edit your original post to supply the details.